# Android SDK win 7

Tags: android, android-emulator

Every time I run the android emulator I receive this message. What should I do to fix it?

> emulator: ERROR: no search paths found in this AVD's configuration.
>   Weird, the AVD's config.ini file is malformed. Try re-creating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using win7 and I have no problem. The config.ini and other files for AVD are actually located on

> ```
> c:\Users*your_username*.android.
> ```

However, I think maybe you are running the shell command to create the AVD? If so, maybe you should change the path where you run it. If you path to run the shell command contains whitespace or non-ascii character, you might see the error message. Classic Windows path problems.